# Optimize image that does not have an image style

Tags: 8, hooks, media

We are using the [imageapi_optimize](https://www.drupal.org/project/imageapi_optimize) modules with the [imageapi_optimize_resmushit](https://www.drupal.org/project/imageapi_optimize_resmushit). We are able to flush the caches for all the image styles and see an improvement. However, there are images that are loaded with `background-image` attribute that do not get optimized and their image styles are set to `Original Image` under `Manage Display` for the `image` field.

**How can I set up the image who use the `Original Image Styles` setting under `Manage Display` to be optimized as well?**

What we tried:

1. Enable `imageapi_optimize`
2. Enabled `imageapi_optimize_resmushit`
3. Setup `image optimize pipeline` and set it to `resmushit`
4. Clear all caches and especially the image style cache using `drush if all`
5. Observe all images where an image style is used other than `Original Image` is optimized after cache.
6. All images where image style is set to `Original Image` is not not optimized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `background-image` refers to the example: `<img src="" style="background-image: url(path/to/image);" />`.

Background images are different when written as: `style="background-image: url(path/to/image);"`, they do not necessarily use Drupal's render service.

A couple of options to try depending on your use case:

• Try preprocessing your image field URI and then printing out the Image Style image path.

```
use Drupal\image\Entity\ImageStyle;

$imagePath = 'public://images/image.jpg';
$variables['imageStyleURL'] = ImageStyle::load('style_name')->buildUrl($imagePath);

url({{ imageStyleURL }})
```

• Change the output format of the field to "URL to image", then just print out {{ image_field }} in the `url()`.

```
url({{ image_field }})
```

The problem to your question, is how would Drupal (or contributed module) know that an image URL should be processed by an image style? It would not seem an issue with the modules, more they don't have a chance to do their thing.

Also, [Twig Tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak), beyond being a great module for many cases, provides a Twig method for applying an image style in Twig:

```
{{ field_image_path | image_style('image_style') }}
```

*Note, manual image URL's that contain an image style path will use that image style: `/sites/default/files/styles/image_style/public/pictures/2019-03/file_name.jpg_11`

Comment: `Change the output format of the field to "URL to image"` combined with setting an image style resolved the problem